# JQuery Nested Conditional

Tags: jquery, nested, conditional-statements

Is it possible to nest conditional statements in JQuery? The code below works if I strip off the outside if but once I add it back it stops working. Can someone tell me if this is even possible? I don't want to go too far checking my syntax for nothing.

```
$("input[title$='Derived']").click(function() {
    if ($("input[title$='Derived']").is(":checked")) {
        var r = confirm("This will clear the values of the Original Module and Amount Reused fields. Do you wish to continue?");
            if (r==true) {
                $('input[title="Original Module"]').val('');
                $('input[title="Amount Reused"]').val('');
                $("nobr:contains('Original Module')").closest('tr').toggle();
                $("nobr:contains('Amount Reused')").closest('tr').toggle();
            }
            else {
                alert("You pressed Cancel!");
            }
    else {
        alert("Test!");
    }
    });
```

As a side note, the alert("You pressed cancel!"); and alert("Test!"); are placeholders. I actually don't want those elses to do anything.

Comment: There is nothing fundamentally wrong with nesting ifs, which would indicate there is something else wrong in the code.

Comment: shouldn't the first if be: if ($(this).is(":checked")) {.....
On a side note, yes, you can do it, there is nothing wrong with having that if statement.

Comment: Looks like you are missing a closing bracket for your outer if statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[title$='Derived']").click(function() {
    if ($("input[title$='Derived']").is(":checked")) {
         if(confirm("Message here"))
         {
            //do something
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the line:

```
else {
```

To:

```
} else {
```

Also, as  AD.Net pointed out, you might want to replace the second `$("input[title$='Derived']")` with `$(this)`.